# flutter add user data after google sign in

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a problem with save user data to firestore i using sign in with google auth so after i want to add user data to firestore so i can not do this can you help me thanks.

this is my auth code

```
 
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount? get user => _user;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool result = false;

  Future googleLogin()async {
    try {
      final googleUSer = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleUSer == null ) return;
      _user = googleUSer;
      final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      final googleAuth = await googleUSer.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      );
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    User? user = userCredential.user;
    if (user != null){
      if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(
            {
              'username': user.displayName,
              'uid': user.uid,
              'profilePhoto': user.photoURL,
            }
        );
      }}
    return result;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
  Future logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try add idToken in credential. 
`final OAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken,);`

Answer (score 0):

Hey were you able to save the user to firestore? I have pasted the answer that worked for me.

```
final userGoogle = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
await _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(cred.user!.uid)
          .set({
uid: userGoogle.uid,
        name: userGoogle.displayName!,
        email: userGoogle.email!,
        photoURL: userGoogle.photoURL!,
});
```

I'm curious if this would mean that every time I login using the google account, the photo from the Google account would overwrite the photoURL, assuming it was updated from let's say the profile page. Could help little insight into it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).